# Appropriate Hosting Plan?

Tags: magento-1.9, hosting

I just finish my size optimizatoin.

```
http://gtmetrix.com/reports/modernmarkt.com/jpqes948
```

Since my site is still very slow i think my problem is with the low server because i have over 20.000product and 100.000images.
Now i use Siteground's Magento Cloud Hosting with 
2 x 3.0 GHz CPU Cores, CentOS, 2GB RAM, 50GB SSD.
Its cost me about 70euro.
For the same amount i could choose Mochahost's Barista-3 cloud server with 6gb ram, 4x9GHz cpu and 200gb space which is much better but not Magento hosting.
Should i change to Mochahost or Spend more on Siteground.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I think you should spend some more and continue with siteground. Its highly secured and reliable. Else go for Amezon AWS.

Comment: For the same price or less I'm sure we could help. Our shared plans would be able to handle that many products and images without issue. See our [magento optimized shared hosting](http://www.snapfast.com/magento-optimized-hosting/shared/) for details. Our support will help you configure Magento for performance.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem might not be your host (the small amount of memory however could be causing paging).

Your time to first byte is what's slowing the load of all the other assets on your site. They're many factors that come into this: Magento is fairly resource heavy, inefficient trips to the database, inefficient 3rd party modules.

You should profile your store and question the output, see if you can refactor code to make it more efficient, use block caching to cache what you can't refine anymore.
http://fbrnc.net/blog/2012/08/magento-profiler

Services like NewRelic will also give you incredibly detailed feedback on exactly what's going on within your store: Database, Stack, Page load time etc...

Throwing more money and hardware at the problem helps but isn't necessarily the answer to your problems.

Don't go with a host just because they say they're Magento hosting, they're very few I would personally rate. Review each one individually and what they offer, if they're a cloud provider run a test environment for a few days and simulate load to see how your site performs.

Comment: And when i had just a few item and not 20.000 it was fast enough.

Comment: That's all the more reason to investigate. The slowdown could be related to memory, database configuration, index size, any new functionality that's been added. It would be worth upping to a package with more Memory if you're running the db/web server on the same instance, but it's not the whole solution.

Comment: The problem seems to be with the First Time Byte.Everything else i properly configurated.

Answer (score 0):

I think Mochahost will be better because Magento is nothing but of a CMS. So, if Mochahost gives you better configuration for the same price, then Mochahost would be better.

Comment: I think it also depends on server software configuration, not only hardware performance.

Answer (score 0):

I would stay with Siteground and try to identify the specific bottleneck you're running into, or talk to a hosting company that has already set up a hosting service optimized for Magento, and can advise you on the appropriate configuration. I would recommend [Nexcess](https://www.nexcess.net/magento/hosting) for this.

Comment: Nexces maybe good but Siteground advertised itself as Magento Hosting but they seem nothing to know about it.

Comment: @peterc I have talked to very few hosts who actually know how to optimize their platform for Magento. Rackspace and Nexcess were in the top of the list. Technically, almost any web host can run Magento, but they don't all employ Magento experts, unfortunately.